# web.xml not found during maven build of Tomcat application

Tags: mysql, maven, tomcat, openshift

I am receiving the following error when pushing a J2EE app to my OpenShift Tomcat application:

```
remote: [INFO] Webapp assembled in [40 msecs]
remote: [INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/54eb9daa5973ca7b9a0000d9/app-    root/runtime/repo/webapps/ROOT.war
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 4.339s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 25 14:51:14 EST 2015
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/112M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project dragonfly: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
remote: [ERROR] 
remote: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote: [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote: [ERROR] 
remote: [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have my web.xml in webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml and in .openshift/config/web.xml

I'm also confused about webapp vs. WebContent.

Answer (score 0):

The `web.xml` file must be placed under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. The error you are getting is because Maven is not finding `web.xml` at this location.

Also, I will take a wild guess but I presume `WebContent` is the folder generated by Eclipse when you create a web-application. If this folder is present, then there is a issue with your Eclipse project configuration. You should follow [Maven conventions](http://maven.apache.org/maven-conventions.html) through out your project (and add the Maven nature to your Eclipse project with the [m2e plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/)).

Comment: I have a fully functional J2EE application, and can export it as a WAR file, and the WebContent folder needs to be served with php support. On my test system I use symbolic links from the php web root to this folder. I do not want to change my J2EE app to be maven specific, what is the best way for me to deploy my application at OpenShift?